# Googleスプレッドシートで黄色のセルだけを違うシートに抽出するマクロの作成方法

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

2023のシートの黄色セルをパイプラインというシートに抽出する方法につき、下記コードをApps Scriptに入れてみましたが機能しませんでした。コード自体に誤りがあるのでしょうか。ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
function extractYellowCells() {
  var sourceSheetName = "2023"; // 抽出したいデータのあるシート名
  var targetSheetName = "パイプライン"; // 抽出したデータを貼り付けるシート名
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getBackgrounds();
  var targetValues = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < sourceValues[i].length; j++) {
      if (sourceValues[i][j] == "#ffff00") { // #ffff00 は黄色のセルの背景色コードです
        row.push(sourceSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getValue());
      } else {
        row.push("");
      }
    }
    targetValues.push(row);
  }
  
  targetRange.setValues(targetValues);
}
```

Comment: スクリプトの効率を無視してスクリプトを拝見しますと、"2023"シートにおいて`#ffff00`をbackgroundColorとするセルの値は同じ座標で"パイプライン"シートへコピーされると思われます。このため、残念ながら`機能しませんでした`を理解できません。その詳細をお教えいただけないでしょうか。もしもセルの値がコピーされない場合は、シート名やセルのbackgroundColorなどを再確認するのはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

以下の通り書き換えてみて各セルの背景色の値を確認してみてはいかがですか？

**元のコード:**

```
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < sourceValues[i].length; j++) {
      if (sourceValues[i][j] == "#ffff00") { // #ffff00 は黄色のセルの背景色コードです
        row.push(sourceSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getValue());
      } else {
        row.push("");
      }
    }
    targetValues.push(row);
  }
```

**修正例:**

```
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < sourceValues[i].length; j++) {
        row.push(sourceValues[i][j]);
    }
    targetValues.push(row);
  }
```

それから背景色だけを配列に取得してforループ内で毎回getRange(...)getValue()していますが、同じセル範囲から背景色はcolorsという配列に、値をvaluesという配列にそれぞれ取得しておいて、forループのなかで背景色colors[i][j]が黄色である時のi,jのインデックスでvalues[i][j]をrowにプッシュするように変更すれば効率が良くなると思います。